# Instruction in Controller "sometimes" executed multiple times instead of once in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to have a column in the database incremented each time a post page is viewed.
For this, I added the following before serving the view in the Controller function that creates the post:

```
    public function index($id) {
        $post= Post::find($id);
        if($post){
            //I have here SEOMeta, OpenGraph and Twitter data settings...
            $viewedPost = Post::where('id', $id);
            $viewedPost ->increment('hits');
        }
        $meta = SEOMeta::generate() . OpenGraph::generate() . Twitter::generate();
        return view('post', compact('post', 'related', 'comments', 'meta'));
        } else{
        abort(404);
```

I have noticed that with this code, "hits" incrementation is sometimes looping for a same view ending up with a wrong number of views especially when there is a heavy load on the website. *(I confirmed this by replacing the increment() instruction with saving the SessionID and IP of the user in a table. I ended up with duplicate lines with the same SessionID and IP).*

I tried to find a work around by saving the SessionID for the viewed post to make sure that it does not exist before executing the incrementation:

```
$user_session_id = Request::getSession()->getId();
        if (Session::has($id))
        {
            $exists = false;
            foreach(Session::get($id) as $existing_session):
            if ($existing_session == $user_session_id)
            {
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }
            endforeach;
            if (!$exists)
            {
                $viewedPost = Post::where('id', $id);
                $viewedPost ->increment('hits');    
            }               
            Session::push($id, $user_session_id);
        }
        else
        {
            Session::put($id, $user_session_id);
            $viewedPost = Post::where('id', $id);
            $viewedPost ->increment('hits');
        }
```

With this, increment() is not supposed to execute for the same SessionID and same post until the session expires (after 120min). However, as I kept refreshing the page, the increment() was executing each time.

I need help to find what I am doing wrong in this work around (an alternative solution is also welcome as long as it does the requested job).

*Side note: I am not a web developer, please forgive my ignorance if I am missing anything important.*

Comment: Can you share your `route` and `model` as well ??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a working solution using Cookies instead of Session by simply doing this (probably not the best but does the job until someone gives a better solution):

```
        if (!(Cookie::has((string)$id)))
        {
            $viewedPost = Post::where('id', $id);
            $viewedPost ->increment('hits');
        }
        Cookie::queue((string)$id, true, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maibe if you create an event like "retrieved" and a listener associated will be more elegant and clean and every time you retrieve a post the listener will be called and incremented.

- create a property $dispatchesEvents on your Post Class;
- create an Event like Post\Retrieved;
- create a Listener like Post\IncrementName_of_column;
  (here you just call $event->post->increment())
- Register Event on EventServiceProvider;

You can see more about here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

Hope you enjoy!